# Tratando dados WebSevice json

Tags: php, json, web-service

Ao executar uma url me retorna os dados abaixo. estou tentando trata-lo mais não sei como fazer pois e a primeira vez que trabalho com json e as variaveis estão vazias oque estou fazendo de errado já lim em outros postes mais não encontrei a solução

```
[{"n_recep2":95000,"dt_exame":"2012-08-30","nome_pac":"MARISA OLIVEIRA SILVA","desconv":"IPE","idade":56,"cpf":"75298848087","desconv_1":"IPE","nome_pac_1":"MARISA OLIVEIRA SILVA","titulo":"MAMOGRAFIA / ECOGRAFIA MAMÁRIA:","resultado":"{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\deflang1046{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fnil\\fcharset0 Arial;}{\\f1\\fnil\\fcharset0 Tahoma;}}\r\\viewkind4\\uc1\\pard\\fs22 Estudo conjunto de mamografia e ecografia mam\\'e1ria.\\f1\\par\r\\f0 Pele, tecido subcut\\'e2neo, ar\\'e9ola e regi\\'e3o retroareolar sem altera\\'e7\\'f5es.   \\par\rMamas densas mostrando distribui\\'e7\\'e3o assim\\'e9trica e heterog\\'eanea do tecido fibroglandular.\\par\rCalcifica\\'e7\\'f5es benignas em ambas as mamas. \\par\rA mama esquerda mostra no raio de 12h. uma forma\\'e7\\'e3o c\\'edstica. Mede em torno de 5.5 x 3.9  mm.\\par\rAus\\'eancia de n\\'f3dulos suspeitos ou microcalcifica\\'e7\\'f5es patol\\'f3gicas.        \\par\rLinfonodos de aspecto n\\'e3o suspeito no prolongamento axilar esquerdo.    \\par\r                   \\f1    \\par\r\\f0\\tab Achados benignos.\\par\r\\tab BI-RADS categoria-2.\\f1\\par\r\\f0\\par\r\\par\r\\par\r\\par\r                    Favor trazer os exames anteriores ao realizar mamografia.\\par\r\\par\r\\f1\\par\r\\f0\\par\r}\r."}]


//string json contendo os dados do paciente
 $json_str = 'http://xxx.70.67.242:4040/api/laudos/95000,75298848087';
//faz o parsing na string, gerando um objeto PHP
 $obj = json_decode($json_str);

//imprime o conteúdo do objeto 
echo "n_recep2: $obj->n_recep2<br>"; 
echo "nome_pac: $obj->nome_pac<br>"; 
echo "resultado: $obj->resultado<br>";
```

Comment: Mas vc tá parseando uma url, ao invés da string json. Entende isso?

Comment: eu tenho que consumir essa url que está ai, ela é de terceiros

Comment: Nesse caso, tem que fazer uma requisição. Não é só fazer uma string com a url e esperar que ela faça a requisição. xD. Vou formular uma resposta pra vc. Conhece curl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como já mencionado no meu comentário, você está parseando uma `string` simples que recebeu a URL do webservice que você quer consumir:

```
//string json contendo os dados do paciente
 $json_str = 'http://xxx.70.67.242:4040/api/laudos/95000,75298848087';
//faz o parsing na string, gerando um objeto PHP
 $obj = json_decode($json_str);
```

Não vai funcionar! Pelo menos não dessa forma.

O que você precisa é fazer uma requisição que vai retornar esse JSON. Para tal, usamos o `cURL`:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array(
    $curl,
    array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://xxx.70.67.242:4040/api/laudos/95000,75298848087',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    )
);

$json_str = curl_exec($curl);

$obj = json_decode($json_str);
$obj = $obj[0];

//print_r($obj);

echo "n_recep2: $obj->n_recep2<br>";
echo "nome_pac: $obj->nome_pac<br>";
echo "resultado: $obj->resultado<br>";
```

Lógico que essa é uma requisição simples. O cURL vai muito além! Recomendo a leitura da [documentação do cURL no manual do PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php).